# Dunders no longer combined in Pycharm?

Tags: python, pycharm

I recently switched to the new Pycharm version and in the contrary to the previous versions it seems like two underscores are no longer combined like this: __

Does someone know how to switch it back, so the IDE combines them?

Comment: ...what do you mean by "combined"? The characters must necessarily still be two underscores, otherwise the code wouldn't work. It sounds like maybe you're just using a different font?

Comment: I mean by combined that it is shown like this: __ and not this: _ _

Comment: The font changed slightly to but do you know the previuosly used font?

Comment: This sounds like a useful feature to me: it's much easier to see just how many underscores there are.  This might lead to fewer questions along the lines of "my class won't take any parameters, even though I clearly defined parameters in my `_init_()`"...

Comment: I have no idea, but there are plenty of fonts with programming ligatures that likely do this and much more, e.g. showing `->` as `→` (wide, so it still takes up the space of two characters). Hasklig, Fira Code, Inconsolata, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to enable: `File - Settings - Editor - Font - Enable font ligatures`